# Правильно ли стоит запятая?

Tags: запятые

> Ты ещё не знаешь, на кого поступать будешь?

Answer (score 0):

В данном предложении есть *однородные сказуемые* (Ты ещё **не знаешь** (,) на кого **поступать будешь**?), эти сказуемые относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему (`ты`). Между ними нет союза `и`, значит....

> надо ставить запятую: Ты ещё не знаешь, на кого поступать будешь?